# Increase Meebo font size

Tags: font, meebo

Is there any way to increase the font size in Meebo?

Ideally I want the layout to not be affected (i.e. it shouldn't look broken), and I want the setting to only apply to Meebo and not all the other websites I visit.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome, there is an extension called [Font Size Increase](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ombpcpigmndepfckcifdblemkabaoihk?hl=en-gb) that may be of use to you.

If you use Firefox there is an add-on called [NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint/) which can be set for all sites or specific sites.